# Are Microsoft's OpenAPI definitions of their Power Automate components available?

Tags: openapi, power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector, microsoft-documentation

I was reading through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#when-a-site-has-requested-to-join-a-hub-site) for the SharePoint API in PowerAutomate and I noticed that the **Returns** category of certain actions is undefined in the docs, however in the PowerAutomate page I can see the possible outputs for this particular trigger.

[image: Outputs for the trigger are visible in PowerAutomate]

I have [searched a bit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/custom-connectors/define-openapi-definition) and found that PowerAutomate uses OpenAPI to define the inputs/outputs, so I was wondering where I could find these OpenAPI definitions for the functions and triggers used by Microsoft.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Most of the Microsoft connectors are from [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). If you want the OpenAPI definition of those then you can find them @ https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/tree/dev/openApiDocs/v1.0. And one other link to third-party connectors: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors

Comment: @SamNseir tysm, this is EXACTLY what I needed, do you want to add an answer so I can mark it as resolved ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the Microsoft connectors are from [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0).

If you want the OpenAPI definition of those then you can find them @ https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/tree/dev/openApiDocs/v1.0

And one other link to third-party connectors: https://github.com/microsoft/PowerPlatformConnectors